# Device not detected in VS code for flutter

Tags: flutter

In VS code my device is not detected. I have enabled Debugging options and developer's option on my Android device but still not working. Help please.

Comment: Try turning off USB Debugging and enabling it again, also restart your system

Comment: @Prashant I tried it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check all of this:

- Make sure USB Debugging is enabled on your phone.
- From Android Studio -> SDK Manager make sure "Google USB Driver" is installed
- Make Sure that Flutter extension is installed on VSCode
- Try restarting your PC